# Downloading Excel file xlsx in Angularjs and WebApi

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, excel, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a task, in which I have to download a report in xlsx format. The report file is generated successfully from server, and is received on client side as well. But it is not opening and producing invalid format error.
Below is the code of server side.

```
var output = await reportObj.GetExcelData(rParams);
    if (output != null){
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(output.ConentBytes)
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = output.FileName
        };
 return result;
 }
```

Here is the code for client side:

```
        var saveData = function (response) {

        if (response.status === 200) {
            var reportData = response.data;

            var b = new Blob([reportData], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
            saveAs(b,"ReportFile.xlsx");//this is FileSaver.js function
        } else {
            console.log(response.statusText);
        }

    };


    $scope.getExcelFile = function(reportName, reportParams) {

        reportDataService.getExcelReportData(reportName, reportParams, saveData);

    }
```

**Below is the error message:**
Excel could not open newFile.xlsx because some content is unreadable. Do you want to open and repair this workbook?
**On clicking repair, following error appears:**
Excel cannot open this file.
The file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Can some one guide me what I am doing wrong? Meanwhile, the same server side file generator objects works smoothly in ASP.Net forms application, and the file opens without any error as well.

Thank you.

Comment: what's you `$http` config? please add the request line.

Comment: config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + authData.token;
This is just for authorization purpose.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I expect your `$http` call is missing the response type configuration. This is the way I download office files:

```
function download(url, defaultFileName) {
    var self = this;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(url, { responseType: "arraybuffer" }).then(
        function (data, status, headers) {
            var type = headers('Content-Type');
            var disposition = headers('Content-Disposition');
            if (disposition) {
                var match = disposition.match(/.*filename=\"?([^;\"]+)\"?.*/);
                if (match[1])
                    defaultFileName = match[1];
            }
            defaultFileName = defaultFileName.replace(/[<>:"\/\\|?*]+/g, '_');
            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type });
            saveAs(blob, defaultFileName);
            deferred.resolve(defaultFileName);                    
        }, function (data, status) {
            var e = /* error */
            deferred.reject(e);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: You save my day, Thanks!

Comment: All I currently get is an Excel file with the content "(object)" in its first cell

Comment: Your answer has an error and it took me a while to get this to work. The 2nd argument `data` shouldn't be there (it's undefined and shouldn't be there anyway). At the end, this is the line that I use `$http.get(url, { responseType: "arraybuffer" }).success()` and everything works.

Comment: I am getting [Object object] in my first column. Did any one have solution for this

Comment: i try it and script getting me — ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $q

Comment: @ЕвгенийБалашов  hansmaad  can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43894768/how-to-set-the-no-of-column-name-while-export-the-excel-using-angularjs

Comment: response type solve the problem, thank you @hansmaad.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same error , content was in hexa format, so i added a response type as arraybuffer, problem got resolved. please see below.

```
$http({
    url: '/api/sendPMOToBackendUpdate',
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
    data: backendTsData,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).success(function(data, status, headers){
    var file = new Blob([ data ], { type : 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
    var defaultFileName ="TSC-"+$scope.user.name+"-"+$scope.user.ohrId+".xls";
    saveAs(file,defaultFileName);
}).error(function(err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You a just need to do one thing only that.
include following js to save file locally. Download it from
"https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/"
your response data should be in blob type.

I have implemented it and its working.

```
function downloadfile(url,defaultFileName){
  var self = this;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(url, { responseType: "blob" }).then(
       function (data){
          saveAs(data.data, defaultFileName)
          deferred.resolve(defaultFileName);                    
        }, function (data) {
           var e = /* error */
            deferred.reject(e);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43894768/how-to-set-the-no-of-column-name-while-export-the-excel-using-angularjs

Comment: 1 this is the best solution

Comment: changing response type to blob is what finally worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when writing excel using Javascript library Excel Builder. At the end, I found the reason was that a control character '\u001a' was included in data.

The solution is to **encode the control char in Excel's way** as '_x001a_'.

The way I diagnosed the problem was like this:

.xlsx file is just a zipped xml file. You can open it with 7-zip. Inside the `xl/` folder there is a file `sharedString.xml` containing all strings. Extract the file and open it with Notepad++. If you see any control character, then it might be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

first install these module

```
import * as Excel from 'exceljs';
import * as fs from 'file-saver';
```

In your function write these

```
 const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
  var worksheet =  workbook.addWorksheet('sheet');
  worksheet.columns = [
    { header: 'Id', key: 'id', width: 10 },
    { header: 'Name', key: 'name', width: 32 }
  ];
 var buff = workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(function (data) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
    fs.saveAs(blob, "publications.xlsx");
  });
```

Fs is used to access file system and download file. You can also insert img 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#images