# How to automatically download a xlsx file(in angularjs 1) sent by server

Tags: angularjs, blob

The HTTP response for a POST request that I am getting from server side is a xlsx file.How do I download the file in angularjs 1?

Note: *res.download()* won't work here,since its a POST request that I am making,and *res.download()* works only for GET request

Comment: Refer to this answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link#19328891

Comment: duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134961/downloading-excel-file-xlsx-in-angularjs-and-webapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shall work :

```
$http.post("url_here", post_data_to_send, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})

     .success(function (data,status,headers) {

                var blob = new Blob([data]);
                var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.style = "display:none";
                a.href = objectUrl;
                a.download = headers().filename;
                a.click();                        
                console.log("Report downloaded");

                }).error(function (err) {

                    console.log(err);

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly on `Client Side`, you may have some cross-browser compatibility issues (the best way is always to provide a download stream via server, for large files for example).

```js
// this example uses a JSON String 
// but you can do it with any valid blob argument
const fileContent = [JSON.stringify(
  ['something', 'to', 'download'], null, 2
)];

const downloader = document.createElement('a');

// set the filename here
downloader.download = 'filename.json';

const blob = new Blob(fileContent, {type: 'text/plain'});
downloader.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);


// trigger the download
downloader.click();
```

In my opinion, a redirect to the downloadable resource could be the best choice.